# xmpppy. filedescriptor out of range in select

Tags: python, select, xmpp

I am using xmpppy. I create over 50 threads of xmpp connections. Some time later i get an error:

> `File "transports.py", line 199, in pending_data`
>   `return select.select([self._sock],[],[],timeout)[0]   ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()`

Why it happens?

P.S. Sorry for my language.

Comment: This can sometimes indicate that you're running out of file descriptors, which can happen very easily in a multithreaded environment if you're not properly closing your files/connections.  Under Linux, you can see a list of open files for your application (while it is running) by looking in `/proc/<pid>/fd/`, where `<pid`> is the process ID of your program.  If this is large (approaching 1024), you may (a) have a problem with your code or (b) need to increase the open file limit for your program.

Answer (score 4):

xmpppy uses the [select()](http://man.cx/select%282%29) system call to monitor open connections. Unfortunately select() has a pretty awkward limitiation - on most systems it can only monitor connections with a file descriptor number up to a certain limit, often 1024.

This means that as you open more files and connections, eventually you will reach the limit.

The solution would be for xmpppy to use poll() or a more modern (but OS-specific) API such as epoll or kqueue. All of these can be accessed via Python's ['select' module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html).